# Calculating percentages and scores

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

Lets say I have data which looks like:

```
ID   A1Q A2Q B1Q B2Q Continued
23      1  2 2 3 
24      1  2 3 3
```

To understand the table it translates into, Person with ID 23 had answers 1,2,2,4 for the questions A1,A2,B1,B2 respectively. I want to know how to know the percentage of students who answered 1, 2 or 3 in the entire dataset.

I have tried using

```
PROC FREQ data = test.one;
tables A2Q-A2Q;
tables B1Q-B2Q;
RUN;
```

But this does not get me what I want. It separately analyzes each question and the output is long. I just need it into one table that tells me this percentage answered 1, this percentage answered 2 and etc.

The output could be:

```
Question:         1    2   3
Percentage A1Q    40%  40%  20%
Percentage A2Q    60%  20%  20%
Total Percentage  30%  30%  40%
```

So it would translate such that 40% people chose 1, 40% chose 2, and 30% chose 3 for question A1Q. The total percentage is out of all the people that gave answers, 30% chose 1 30% chose 2 and 40% chose 3.

Comment: Can you add a few more rows and demonstrate what you want your output to look like?

Comment: Sure, ill edit the original post.

Comment: Done, thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd still need to work on it a little bit and transpose the final results but this could be a start... also if you have lots of questions, consider wrapping this up in a macro program.

```
data quest;
input ID  A1Q A2Q B1Q B2Q;
datalines;
21 2 3 1 2
22 3 2 2 3
23 1 2 2 3 
24 1 2 3 3
25 2 1 3 3
run;

options missing = 0;    

proc freq data=quest;
  table A1Q / nocol nocum nofreq out = freq1(rename=(A1Q=Answer Count=A1Q));
  table A2Q / nocol nocum nofreq out = freq2;
  table B1Q / nocol nocum nofreq out = freq3;
  table B2Q / nocol nocum nofreq out = freq4;
run;

proc sql;
  create table results as
    select freq1.Answer,
           freq1.Percent as pctA1Q,
           freq2.Percent as pctA2Q,
           freq3.Percent as pctB1Q,
           freq4.Percent as pctB2Q
      from freq1
        left join freq2 
          on freq1.Answer = freq2.A2Q
        left join freq3
          on freq1.Answer = freq3.B1Q
        left join freq4
          on freq1.Answer = freq4.B2Q;
quit;
```

[image: Output Table]

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Proc Tabulate but it might be worthwhile exploring that avenue, as suggested by @Reeza

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to transpose your data and then do a proc freq or proc tabulate. I would recommend proc tabulate so you can format your output, since it looks like you have questions that are grouped.

```
 data long;
    set have;

    array qs(*) a1q--b2q; *list first and last variable and everything in between will be included;

    do i=1 to dim(qs);
       question=vname(qs(i));
       response=qs(i);
       output;
     end;

     keep id question response;
 run;

 proc freq data=long;
     table question*response/list;
 run;
```